# How to check which user is registered and to hide tags with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, backbone.js

I make site and register form with Spring Security. Now, I have a problem. When user registered, I want to check which user is registered and he can see button from edit and delete only on his profile page. When go on page another user, button from edit and delete to hide from him ...  I don't know how in Backbone to check which user is registered and to call hide() if he not on own page. Or exist another better way to hide button from some users?  In View model, I have main.js, standardLayout.jsp, and templates.jsp .

Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
TablesPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#container'), 
        template : _.template($('#tablesPageView').html()), 
        initialize : function() {
            this.render();
            this.getTables();
        },
        render : function (){
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
        },
        getTables : function (){
            new TableCollectionView({ el : $('#tablesTable tbody')});
        }

    });
 TableCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
        model : new TableCollection,
        initialize : function (){
            var self = this;
            this.model.fetch({
                success : function (){
                    self.render();
                },
            error:function (){
                alert("Vrednosti Users nisu ucitane u kolekciju!!!");
            },
        });
        },
        render : function (){
            for(var key in this.model.models){              
                var table = this.model.models[key];
                var tableItemView = new TableItemView({model : table});
                var domU1 = tableItemView.render().el;
                $(this.el).append(domU1);
            }
        }
    });

    TableItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName : "tr" ,
        template : _.template($('#tableItemPageView').html()),
        events : {
            "click #removeTable" : "removeTable"
        },
        initialize : function() {

        },
        render : function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template({ table : this.model.toJSON() })); 
            return this;
        },
        removeTable : function() {
            this.model.destroy(); 
            $(this.el).remove(); 
            return false; 
        },
    });
```

templates.jsp ...

```
<script type="text/template" id="tablesPageView">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9" id="center">
<table id="tablesTable" class="table table-striped text-center">
<thead>
    <tr class="info">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Changed</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<br /><button onclick="window.location.href='#tables/add'">Add</button>
</div>
</script>


<script type="text/template" id="tableItemPageView">
<td><@= table.id @></td>                
            <td><a href="#table/<@=table.typeTable@>/<@= table.id @>" title="Show <@= table.name
 @>"><@= table.name @></td></a>
            <td><@= table.changed @></td>
            <td><@= table.description @></td>
            <td ><a href="#tables/edit/<@=table.id@>">Edit </a><a  
 href="#tables/show/<@=table.id@>"> Players</a><a id="removeTable">  Delete</a>     
 </script>
```

Comment: _I don't know how in Backbone to check which user is registered_. Backbone is just a framework, not a thing ready-to-use. You're defining the logic of your app yourself, Backbone cannot do it for you.

Comment: OK, but, if backbone can't(main.js) , who can check which user is login and hide some button . I use Spring MVC , Model, Controller and View(Backbone.JS) . Controller checks the validity of the users and  preparation model to view, then send html code. I only can call hide() in main.js and hide button ... is there another way?